# Using Postmaster to send system emails

Tags: email, postmaster

I have Postmaster installed, and parcels set up to handle email notifications of channel entries/status changes etc. This uses Mandrill and works fine.

I would like to utilise Mandrill for the sending of system emails, (new member notification/activation etc) and know that this is possible with Postmaster, but I'm not quite sure how to set it up.

Has anyone else done this, or maybe have a screen shot on how to set it up on the Postmaster CP?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you emailed support, and I got back with you earlier. I went ahead and answered the question here for public record, but if you are still having issues with sending system emails, just get back with me privately using support@objectivehtml.com. If it's not working, then something else is preventing that hook from getting triggered within Postmaster for some unknown reason.

Comment: You did, thanks. Ive marked your response as the answer, and given a little more detail below.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really easy to do with Postmaster. You just have to setup a Hook that uses the "Send System Email" hook.

First click "New Hook.

[image: New hook screenshot]

Then select the "Send System Email" hook. Be sure to check "End Script" or else two emails will send (the one from Postmaster and the original).

[image]

You can see below I have titled the hook "System Emails". This is all that is required to get this working, with the addition to filling in the to email, from email, message and subject. Take a look at this link for the reference of which variables are parsed within this particular hook. Just be sure to prefix all the variables used with the Hooks section with `hook:`.

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/hooks/send-system-email

[image]

Comment: Does the "End Script" option being set to "True" prevent duplicate emails from getting sent? I currently have a similar setup, but we're getting duplicates of the emails, one from Postmaster, and one from EE.

Comment: Yup, the End Script option is required for this hook if you don't want duplicate emails to be sent. In some cases with other hooks, preventing the default action isn't desired. So this option gives the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Escort extension to do that. Really simple to set up:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/escort

Good luck!

Seamus

Comment: I use Escort for this too. I use Postmaster for other emails -- Escort and Postmaster work fine together on the same install.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the user's question. Postmaster can do this just fine and you don't need Escort. Using Escort along with Postmaster is just a preference, as Jay mentioned. Escort is a great product, but if you already have Postmaster then you don't *need* Escort.

Comment: I've marked Justin's response as the answer. I was having problems with mail being sent from EE, and as I was in a hurry, I did actually get Escort as well. I know that it is not needed, but I liked the zero config that it offered. Obviously if I want to customise the emails I have Postmaster to turn to :) Also it's good to know that they place well together.