# HTML Stripped out of Postmaster Emails

Tags: postmaster

I've setup Postmaster to send system emails via Mandrill. Everything's working fine, but, all of the HTML tags are getting stripped out.

Here's a snip from the Message field, which is rendering nicely in Postmaster's preview pane:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>{hook:subject}</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
```

Here's the raw text of the email I'm getting:

```
From: (client name / email redacted)
To:  
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2014 15:28:54 -0600 
Subject: Enclosed is your activation code 

Enclosed is your activation code

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
```

The CSS rules are making it through, but, looks like a `strip_tags()` or something is wiping out the HTML.

There is a setting for "Plain Text Only" in the area for the Mandrill config, but, it is set to false.

Running EE 2.7.2 and Postmaster 1.4.4.

Other than [setting up per this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18423/using-postmaster-to-send-system-emails), and selecting Mandrill as the mechanism, none of the default EE email settings have been touched.

Any thoughts appreciated; will followup ASAP.

**Edit 1: Other Add-ons Interfering?**

Here are the relevant (hopefully) columns from `exp_extensions`; this is happening  during the new member registration process (not sure if it's also happening in other situations); the form is coming from Zoo Visitor, has a Snaptcha captcha, <s>and the user is sent to a Custom System Messages managed page on success,</s> so I suppose there's plenty of room for interference.

```
Assets_ext          channel_entries_query_result        channel_entries_query_result
Shortlist_ext       channel_entries_row                 channel_entries_row
Matrix_ext          channel_entries_tagdata             channel_entries_tagdata
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_safecracker_submit_entry_end   channel_form_submit_entry_end
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_safecracker_submit_entry_start channel_form_submit_entry_start
Snaptcha_ext        comment_field                       comment_form_tagdata
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_cp_js_end                      cp_js_end
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_cp_members_member_create       cp_members_member_create
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_cp_members_member_delete_end   cp_members_member_delete_end
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_cp_members_validate_members    cp_members_validate_members
Superfish_admin_ext cp_menu_array                       cp_menu_array
Channel_images_ext  editor_before_display               editor_before_display
Channel_images_ext  editor_before_replace               editor_before_replace
Channel_images_ext  editor_before_save                  editor_before_save
Minimee_ext         ee_debug_toolbar_add_panel          ee_debug_toolbar_add_panel
Snaptcha_ext        email_form_field                    email_form_form_end
Snaptcha_ext        email_form_validate                 email_form_send_form_start
Postmaster_ext      trigger_hook                        email_send
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_entry_submission_end           entry_submission_end
Postmaster_ext      entry_submission_end                entry_submission_end
Postmaster_ext      entry_submission_ready              entry_submission_ready
Assets_ext          files_after_delete                  files_after_delete
Assets_ext          file_after_save                     file_after_save
Snaptcha_ext        forum_field                         forum_submission_form_end
Snaptcha_ext        forum_validate                      forum_submit_post_start
Snaptcha_ext        forum_field                         forum_threads_template
Snaptcha_ext        freeform_field                      freeform_module_form_end
Snaptcha_ext        freeform_validate                   freeform_module_validate_end
Snaptcha_ext        freemember_register_validate        freemember_register_validation
Snaptcha_ext        comment_validate                    insert_comment_start
Snaptcha_ext        rating_comment_validate             insert_rating_comment_start
Snaptcha_ext        rating_validate                     insert_rating_start
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_member_member_register         member_member_register
Snaptcha_ext        member_register_validate            member_member_register_errors
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_member_member_register_start   member_member_register_start
Snaptcha_ext        member_register_validate_deprecated member_member_register_start
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_member_register_validate_members member_register_validate_members
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_membrr_expire                  membrr_expire
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_membrr_subscribe               membrr_subscribe
System_messages_ext output_show_message                 output_show_message
Snaptcha_ext        proform_field                       proform_create_captcha
Snaptcha_ext        proform_process_captcha             proform_process_captcha
Snaptcha_ext        proform_validate                    proform_validation_end
Snaptcha_ext        rating_comment_field                rating_comment_form_tagdata
Snaptcha_ext        rating_field                        rating_form_tagdata
Snaptcha_ext        safecracker_field                   safecracker_entry_form_tagdata_end
Snaptcha_ext        safecracker_validate                safecracker_submit_entry_start
Snippet_sync_ext    sessions_end                        sessions_end
Zoo_visitor_ext     hook_sessions_end                   sessions_end
System_messages_ext extend_output_class                 sessions_start
Url_helper_ext      set_url_helper                      sessions_start
Snippet_sync_ext    show_full_control_panel_end         show_full_control_panel_end
System_messages_ext template_post_parse                 template_post_parse
Minimee_ext         template_post_parse                 template_post_parse
Snaptcha_ext        user_register_validate              user_register_start
Channel_images_ext  wygwam_before_display               wygwam_before_display
Channel_images_ext  wygwam_before_replace               wygwam_before_replace
Channel_images_ext  wygwam_before_save                  wygwam_before_save
Channel_images_ext  wygwam_config                       wygwam_config
```

**Edit 2: Custom System Messages**

Custom System Messages is installed, but, it shouldn't be involved in this process; on a successful submission, Zoo Visitor is the mechanism directing the browser to a template.

Comment: Just saw this post, it should only be stripping those tags if you have plain text option set to True, but you said you didn't. Do you have any other add-ons that could be conflicting with Postmaster? This seems to indicate, along with your `{unwrap}` tag issue, that there is a conflict, because Postmaster should not be doing either of these things. I plan on taking a look into detail today, but in the mean time take a look at your exp_extensions table and see if any of the hooks used in Postmaster are being used with another add-on.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell I've edited my response above below the "Edit 1" heading. Let me know if there's any other info that would be helpful to you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following up to provide an answer for this question if anyone else runs into this issue. This bug should be fixed in Postmaster v1.4.5. Download the latest copy for a fix.